# Ask with awk per lines in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, awk

I am testing how to add with some lists and I was thinking how to make a cumulative list per line, I understand that I can add a whole line and indicate the number of rows to add:

```
awk '{l+=$1}NR%6==0{print l;l=0}' file
```

```
Numbers     |   Sum per line
1           |      1
2           |      3
4           |      7
0           |      7
0           |      7
7           |     14
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your shown samples, please try following `awk` code.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  OFS=" | "
  print "Numbers","Sum per line"
}
{
  $0=prev?($0 OFS prev+$1):($0 OFS $1)
  prev+=$1
}
1
' Input_file
```